# Serializable outer class in Java when using with Socket

Tags: java, serialization, inner-classes

Here I have two classes ClientToSendCalculable.java

```
    import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ClientToSendCalculable implements Serializable
{
    public ClientToSendCalculable(int port)
    {
        try
        (
            Socket s = new Socket("localhost", port);
            ObjectOutputStream writer = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            ObjectInputStream reader = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        )
        {
            System.out.println("Connection was established!");

            ClientToSendCalculable.Addition addition = new ClientToSendCalculable.Addition();
            addition.firstAddendum = 5;
            addition.secondAddendum = 7;

            writer.writeObject(addition);
            double res = (Double)reader.readObject();

            System.out.println(res);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class Addition implements Calculable, Serializable
    {
        private double firstAddendum, secondAddendum;

        public double calc()
        {
            return firstAddendum + secondAddendum;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new ClientToSendCalculable(7777);
    }
}
```

and ServerToGetCalculable.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ServerToGetCalculable
{
    public ServerToGetCalculable(int port)
    {
        try
         (
             ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);
             Socket s = ss.accept();
             ObjectOutputStream writer = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
             ObjectInputStream reader = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
         )
        {
            System.out.println("Got a client!");

            Calculable calcObj = (Calculable)reader.readObject();
            double res = calcObj.calc();

            writer.writeObject(res);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {new ServerToGetCalculable(7777);}
}
```

My question is why should ClientToSendCalculable.java implement Serializable? I send over Socket only its inner class Addition.java but I don`t send ClientToSendCalculable.java on its own. That is why it seems for me that it would be enough if only Addition.java was Serializable, but if I make ClientToSendCalculable.java not Serializable I get an Exception trying to execute this line of code:

```
writer.writeObject(addition);
```

Comment: Addition is an inner class (non-static) -> it contains a field holding a reference to the enclosing ClientToSendCalculable  instance.

Comment: @Nevay, how can I get the reference?

Comment: @Nevay, ok. I found that: A nested class is a member of its enclosing class. Non-static nested classes (inner classes) have access to other members of the enclosing class, even if they are declared private. Static nested classes do not have access to other members of the enclosing class. As a member of the OuterClass, a nested class can be declared private, public, protected, or package private. (Recall that outer classes can only be declared public or package private.)

Comment: @Nevay, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: @Nevay, thanks a lot! It helped. I added static modifier to the inner class, made the outer class not Serializable and it works! Very great!

Comment: @Nevay, but now I am really interested how I can get a reference to the outer class from the inner class?

Comment: The enclosing instance can be accessed by using OuterClassName.this

Comment: @Nevay, so if I want to access enclosing instance of the outer class from the inner class I can do it by `OuterClassName.this`. But it is impossible to get an instance of the outer class from the nested class because nested classes are not associated with any outer classes and if I want to use an instance of the outer class in the nested class I can only create it with the help of the constructor of the outer class. (Some explanation. Inner class means non-static inner class. Nested class means static inner class). Am I right?

Comment: Almost right. There's no such thing as a "static inner class" in Java. A static _nested_ class is not an inner class. A non-static, that is, instance-level or local nested class is an inner class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Addition.java* is an inner class (non-static) -> it contains a field holding a reference to the enclosing ClientToSendCalculable instance -> that field of the outer class will have to be serialized -> it has to implement Serializable interface.